# How to add CSS to a particular div class using JavaScript, even if there are multiple div classes with the same name?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add CSS style to a particular button class. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="mainPage">
    <div class="pageWithButton">
        <div>
            <a href="" title="Learn more" class="btn btn-default" role="button" target="">Look up
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
<script>
    $('.mainPage').each(function(){
        if($(".pageWithButton")){
            $(".btn").css("padding", "8px, 32px, 1px, 9px")
        }
    })
</script>
```

The problem I'm noticing is that, this JS code is also applying the CSS styles to the other div classes on the page  that have a `btn` class name .  How can I limit the CSS to only be applied inside this `mainPage` `pageWithButton` with `btn`?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is to introduce jquery selector:

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

For your problem, you could write the selector like:

```js
$(".mainPage > .pageWithButton > .btn").css("padding", "8px, 32px, 1px, 9px")
```

In jquery, `$(".a > .b")` means to select elements which have class `b` and have a parent element with class `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

And, you'll need to modify the [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) because `$(".pageWithButton")` is always `true`, regardless of there's an element or not.

```js
$(".mainPage").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".pageWithButton").length > 0) {
        $(this).find(".btn").css("padding", "8px 32px 1px 9px");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainPage">
    <div class="pageWithButton">
        <div>
            <a href="" title="Learn more" class="btn btn-default" role="button" target="">
                Look up
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="" title="Learn more" class="btn btn-default" role="button" target="">Look up</a>
```